How to count number of samples per hour of all metrics matching a given regex?
I can count the number of timeseries of all metrics matching a regex like so:
count ({__name__=~"django.*"}) by (__name__)

I can count the number of samples over an hour of a single metric like so:
sum (count_over_time(django_http_exceptions_total_by_type_created[1h]))

But I can't find the syntax to a query that will count the samples over 1h for
all metrics that have a name matching the regex django.*

Tried that. Getting this error: 422: error when executing query="sum (count_over_time({__name__=~\"django.*\"}}[1h]))" on the time range (start=1731471210000, end=1731492810000, step=15000): argList: unexpected token "}"; want ",", ")"; unparsed data: "}[1h]))"

Replace django_http_exceptions_total_by_type_created with label_replace({__name__=~"django.*"},'name','$1','__name__','(.+)') in second query

you have a duplication of }. But I forgot in initial comment problem with label duplication. You need to create a unique label in each result. See approach with label replacement above.

changed that, but that sums everything to a single variable, which is useful but not what I was looking for. I'm trying to get a list of all the metrics and how much samples they sent over the last hour. adding by (__name__) at the end also gives only a single var

__name__ is already dropped by then. Use by (name) instead.

thank you! That solved it. If you'll want it put it as the answer I'll accept it

I will not. Feel free to self answer.
